# Incapsula/Imperva Blocking Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am currently trying to visit a web page that is using Imperva/Incapsula as their CDN. I am getting blocked in my selenium browser, they can somehow detect that I am using selenium. It works fine on the same IP in Chrome/Firefox. It is ONLY blocked in selenium.

Shows that selenium is blocked
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JEeF.png

Shows that it works in normal Chrome
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jo4b7.png

I have tried the basics, such as spoofing user agent. They are running some obsfucated JS script to detect something that I don't know.

Current code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import names
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
import random
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait


options = Options()
ua = UserAgent()
a = ua.random
user_agent = ua.random
print(user_agent)
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')


driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe', options=options)
driver.get('https://secure.runescape.com/m=weblogin/loginform.ws?mod=www&ssl=1&expired=0&dest=account_settings')
```

Comment: did you get an answer to your question. I'm also facing the same issue. Would like to know from you if you have an answer to this question

Answer (score 0):

use puppeteer with stealth plugin